# Lisp Macros: A practical approach

Tags: lisp, macros

On my way to learn Lisp I have discovered the all powerful and feared so called Macros, then after spending a hard time trying to understand them and their usefulness I said to myself, I FINALLY GOT IT.
I couldn't be more wrong, I was thinking that the only purpose of Macros was to define new control structures and that was all I needed to know until I start reading more and more on the subject and a whole new world has comes to me !

One can use Macros for new **Domain Specific Language**, **Code Transformation** and to avoid **Boilerplate Code**.

Hence, if a few examples at which the aforementioned usages of macros and others as well, with a concise and simple-to-understand explanation could be given it would be really nice.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical reference for LISP macros is 
[On Lisp: Advanced Techniques for Common Lisp](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130305529), by Paul Graham (book version).  It is out of print, and everyone who owns a copy knows what it is worth.  You can
[download](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html) it, but Paul says nine figures got lost somewhere in the ozone.

[Let Over Lambda](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1435712757), by Doug Hoyte, is also good.